# how to comb through an input (equation) and grab variables, disregarding whitespace? (scanf()), (arrays)

Tags: c, input, whitespace, scanf

For my C program, the user enters in "aY + b = c" where a, b, and c are int values and Y is a "symbolic constant."

How does one make it so that "aY+b=c" works as well as "aY   + b =   C" works? Basically, I am unsure of how to utilize scanf() so that I can grab my variables a,b, and c from the user input no matter how many spaces the user decides to input.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `fgets` instead to get the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_EQUATION_LEN (1000)

int main(void)
{
    char equation[MAX_EQUATION_LEN];
    int num, i;

    printf("Enter a equation: ");
    fgets(equation, MAX_EQUATION_LEN, stdin);

    sscanf(equation, "%d", &num);

    i = 0;
    while(equation[i])
    {
        if(!isdigit(equation[i]))
            break;
        else
            i++;
    }

    printf("You entered: %d\n", num);
    printf("Unhandled string data: %s\n", &equation[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Run**

> Enter a equation: 204Y + 52 = 9
>   You entered: 204
>   Unhandled string data: Y + 52 = 9

**Logic**

1. Take the full equation in at one time as a string.
2. Parse the string accordingly.  Here, I'm looking for the first `int`.
3. Keep track of where you are in the string parsing process.
4. Keep parsing the string until there are no more characters.

Comment: @ZumbaLover69: Right, what this answer is showing is the beginnings of a *lexer*. A lexer takes a string and breaks it up into *tokens*; many lexers skip whitespace, some represent them as special whitespace tokens. A *parser* then takes a sequence of tokens and analyzes it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unsure of how to utilize scanf() so that I can grab my variables a,b, and c from the user input no matter how many spaces the user decides to input.

Don't use scanf in the first place. You need to write a lexer and a parser, so **write a lexer and a parser**.